# How to install individual packages in a multiple repository Python project using git branches?

Tags: git, pip

I have a Python project that contains multiple packages, each located in a separate folder under the project root directory. Each package has its own `setup.py` file.

I want to be able to install each package separately using `pip install git+https://github.com/...` command and specifying the git branch for that package.

I tried to install the package using the `pip install git+https://github.com/...` command with the git branch specified, but it failed. Currently, it is searching for the `setup.py` file in the root directory which I don't have.

Is it possible to install individual packages in a multiple repository Python project using git branches? If yes, what are the suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: It is documented here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/

Comment: thanks! the subdirectory solved it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpip%5D+branch+subdirectory

Comment: `pip install git+https://github.com/username/repo.git@branch#egg=subproject&subdirectory=path/to/dubdir`